# Swapping a particular element with the one above it, in a randomly ordered ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

I have a ArrayList from 1 - 9 that is randomly ordered and will be represented in three rows like this order for example:

```
6,5,7
4,8,1
9,2,3
```

It should be noted that I'm working with just a flat list, but I intend to represent it like above later on.

What I need is to be able to always swap the 9 element with the one above it. So for the configuration above I would need to swap the 9 and the 4. This needs to be done for any order where the 9 element might appear.

I've already created a switch statement that should do this when a user presses a key on the keyboard. So the logic of this swap should go in that switch case.

I wrote this code to try and achieve this goal, but it doesn't work as intended.

```
case 'u' :  
     int nineIndex = temp.indexOf(9);
     int nine = 9;
     int indexToSwapTo =  temp.indexOf(9) - 3 % 9;  

     System.out.println("index of 9: " + nineIndex);
     System.out.println("index to swap to : " + indexToSwapTo);

     temp.remove(nineIndex);
     temp.add(nineIndex, indexToSwapTo);

     temp.remove(indexToSwapTo);
     temp.add(indexToSwapTo, nine);

         break;
```

The idea is, I first get the index of the 9 and then to get the index of the item above it I do the index at 9 - 3. I then perform some adds and removes. I should also note that the `temp` is an ArrayList that holds the random configuration of numbers. However this code doesn't work quite as intended. It does this instead:

The randomly order array list produces the following:

```
[6,1,8,3,7,**4**,2,5,**9**]
```

And after a swap occurs as described above, the ArrayList turns into this:

```
[6,1,8,3,7,**9**,2,5,**5**]
```

The printout says this as well which is useful:
**index of 9: 8 index to swap to : 5**. As you can see although it does swap the items in the correct place it for some reason puts index 5 as the item to be swapped rather than the actual value of index 5 which is 4. It also sometimes runs with out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: What happens if 9 be the first element in the list?  Do we rollover swap with the third row?

Comment: Or anywhere in the first row

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   I'm not sure to be honest, the ArrayList isn't actually in rows at the min, but it will be later on, I just want to get the thing working first. I jsut used rows to aid in the explanation for now.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis What do you mean sorry?

Comment: @GR412 just create a new copy of temp and don't remove any element. update elements with new values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `Collections.swap`

You're way overthinking the problem. Just use the API available to you.

```
int nineIndex = temp.indexOf(9);
int indexToSwapTo =  (nineIndex + 6) % 9;
Collections.swap(temp, nineIndex, indexToSwapTo);
```

Note this assumes that when 9 is on the top line, the "above" line is the bottom one, as in a circular way.

Comment: Oh wow i had no idea about this, also is it possible to not make it circular? Because i also intend to have a key that allows it to swap the 9 with the element below it as a seprate key. It would be nice to put a boundry check to say if the 9 is at the top row tne print out an message or something. I could maybe figure that out. Also why is it +6 as opposed to -3? Myh thought was to get the element above 9 you need to go backwards through the arraylist.

Comment: @GR412 The `(index+6)%9` is there to avoid problems when you have an index on the top row. If you use `(index-3)%9` and the 9 is at index 1, for instance, you'll get `(-2)%9`, which is `-2`, which is an invalid index in Java. if you use `(index+6)%9`, then when 9 is at index 1, you get 7, which is a valid index... in the bottom line. If you want special case for the first row (making it not circular or reporting an error), just add a condition: `if (nineIndex < 3) // do something`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `%` operator in Java has a higher precedence than `-` so your line 4 is 
equivalent to
`int indexToSwapTo =  temp.indexOf(9) - 3;`.

This will work, but o**nly for the last two rows**. You should add some **parentheses** around the right hand side to cover every case, like this: 
`int indexToSwapTo = (temp.indexOf(9) - 3 ) % 9;`

Secondly, there is a **logical error** in your code. In particular, in the first code block that adds and removes the ArrayList entries:

```
temp.remove(nineIndex);
temp.add(nineIndex, indexToSwapTo);
```

The second line is wrong, as it attempts to **insert the index of the entry** that you're meant to swap with, and not the **value of that entry**. In your example, the program correctly realises that it needs to swap the ArrayList entries at indices 5 and 8. However, in your code, you are telling the program to store **5** in the position of **9**, instead of telling it to store the contents of index **5** in the position of **9** (which in this case, is the 8th entry of the ArrayList).

To fix your code, you should replace the code block above with this:

```
int value_to_be_swapped = temp.get(indexToSwapTo)
temp.remove(nineIndex);
temp.add(nineIndex, value_to_be_swapped);
```